# Django - Form-Select field set as not required not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form and want to make some fields not required.

It's working for most, but `pairing_rum` field (and a few others) are causing some difficulties. For this question I removed the other fields as they are in the same format as `rum_pairing`.

### Here is what I tried so far:

- using the same format as venue ie `forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Venue.objects.all()` - but how can I filter to only get the choices contained within the field of the model?
- I also tried to modify the forms `__init__`, but no luck (example below - sorry for the formatting, stack is not letting me putting it in a code format)

  def **init**(self, *args, **kwargs):
  super(ReviewRating, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
  self.fields['pairing_rum'].required = False

Which renders the following error:
*super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type*

What would be the best way to make `pairing_rum` field not requried?

### My current code is as follows:

**models**

```
class ReviewRating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="usercomments")     product=models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name="comments",null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    pairing_coffee = models.IntegerField(choices=COFFEE_PAIRING, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    pairing_rum = models.IntegerField(choices=RUM_PAIRING, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    pairing_gin = models.IntegerField(choices=GIN_PAIRING, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    pairing_whisky = models.IntegerField(choices=WHISKY_PAIRING, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    pairing_event = models.ForeignKey(CatalogueEvent, related_name="pairing_event",on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True)
    pairing_venue = models.ForeignKey(Catalogue, related_name="pairing_venue",on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True)
    review =models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    rating =models.IntegerField(choices=RATING, default=0)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, blank=True, null=True, related_name="venues", on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

**forms**

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    venue = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Venue.objects.all(),required=False)
 
    class Meta:
        model = ReviewRating
        fields = ['review', 'rating','venue','pairing_coffee', 'pairing_rum','pairing_gin','pairing_whisky', 'pairing_event','pairing_venue']
        widgets = {
                    'venue': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-select', 'placeholder':'Enter name'}),
                    'pairing_coffee': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-select', 'placeholder':'Enter name'}),
                    'pairing_rum': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-select', 'placeholder':'Enter name'}),
                    'pairing_gin': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-select', 'placeholder':'Enter name'}),
                    'pairing_whisky': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-select', 'placeholder':'Enter name'}),
                    'pairing_event': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-select', 'placeholder':'Enter name'}),
                    'pairing_venue': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-select', 'placeholder':'Enter name'}),
                }
```

**views**

```
def show_product(request, product_id):
    url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    form = ReviewForm()
    submitted = False
    data = Product.objects.filter(pk=product_id).annotate(
            avg_rating =Avg('comments__rating'),) 
    if request.method == "POST" and 'btnreview_form' in request.POST:
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.product_id = product_id
            data.user_id = request.user.id
            data.save()
            form.save()
            return redirect(url)
        else:
            print(form.errors)
        
    else:
        print(form.errors)
    return render(request,"main/show_product.html", {'form':form, 'submitted':submitted, 'product':product, 'venue_form':venue_form, 'data':data})
```

**template**

```
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action="{% url 'show-product' product.id%}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="rate">
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating1" value="1" required /><label for="rating1" title="1"></label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating2" value="2" required /><label for="rating2" title="2"></label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating3" value="3" required /><label for="rating3" title="3"></label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating4" value="4" required /><label for="rating4" title="4"></label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating5" value="5" required /><label for="rating5" title="5"></label>
        </div>
        {%if product.category == 1 %}
        {{ form.pairing_rum|as_crispy_field }}


        {%endif%}
        {%if product.category == 2 %}
        {{ form.pairing_gin|as_crispy_field }}


        {%endif%}
        {%if product.category == 3 %}
        {{ form.pairing_whisky|as_crispy_field }}


        {%endif%}
        {%if product.category == 8 %}
        {{ form.pairing_coffee|as_crispy_field }}


        {%endif%}

        {{ form.review|as_crispy_field }}
        {{ form.venue|as_crispy_field }}
        {% comment %} <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" href ="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddVenueFormModal" ><font size="3px" color="#008083">Can't find the venue?</font></a> {% endcomment %}
        <input type="submit" name="btnreview_form" value="Submit Review" class="btn btn-primary custom-btn">
    </form>
    </br>
    {% else %}
    

    {% endif %}
```

EDITED to add Traceback

The traceback indicates there is a problem at `form.save(commit=False)`

```
[23/Dec/2022 13:53:39] "GET /show_product/109 HTTP/1.1" 200 15414
Internal Server Error: /show_product/109
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CeX\Virtual\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\CeX\Virtual\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CeX\Dev\mysite\main\views.py", line 760, in show_product
    data = form.save(commit=False)
  File "C:\Users\CeX\Virtual\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 539, in save
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The ReviewRating could not be created because the data didn't validate.
```

### New edit following Iain Shelvington's recommendation the error is the following:

Ironically, this is the code that I did deem necessary to be in the post that is causing the problem. Which is weird considering this is a pure copy/paste of the `pairing_rum`. 'pairing_rum` even when empty does not return any error message, but the others do.

```
[23/Dec/2022 14:21:50] "GET /show_product/109 HTTP/1.1" 200 15430
<ul class="errorlist"><li>pairing_coffee<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. 0 is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li><li>pairing_gin<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. 0 is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li><li>pairing_whisky<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. 0 is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Comment: The `pairing_rum` field has `blank=True` so the generated field on the form will not be required. You call `form.save()` twice, could be your issue since the second time you don't set some required fields. Can you share the actual error message you are getting?

Comment: Error message is: `The ReviewRating could not be created because the data didn't validate.`. The form works when 'pairing_rum' is populated, which makes me think this is because the non required fields are still considered as required by Django.

Comment: Can you share the full traceback? Knowing the exact line that triggers the error will help

Comment: Just added it. The error comes from `form.save(commit=False)`. (thanks for sticking around!)

Comment: You should call `form.is_valid()` before `form.save(commit=False)`, all the lines where you manipulate and save `data` should be in the `if form.is_valid():` block. The error messages on the form when it's not valid will give more information on what exactly is not validating

Comment: You are right, I do get a lot more information now I did that. I updated the error message. There is a bit of irony since the error is actually coming from the code I didnt think it was necessary to be in the original post. The error is coming from the other `pairing` fields (but not the rum one), which is weird considering they are just a copy/paste from the `pairing_rum` field. Or I might be missing something?

Comment: You use `default=0` in the model fields but `0` is not a valid choice for those fields? The default is used as the "empty" choice if defined. Removing the default and allowing null values, changing the default to a valid choice or adding `0` to the choices would all work

Comment: I think I figured the problem, not sure how to fix it. The template renders the appropriate `pairingfield` based on the product category. The error seem to happen for the field that are not rendered.

Comment: @IainShelvington what a man! Thanks! Feel free to post your answer, I will validaet it